# Is it good practice to style the panel layout?

Tags: panels, theming

I have a panel layout. I was wondering if its okay to apply additional css ids / classes to this or to style elsewhere? I am using panels everywhere and I have moved the layout into my theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable to add CSS ids and classes to panel layouts.